# Can't open module file using gfortran

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, fortran, mpi, gfortran

I am using gfortran to run an .F90 code, and I am getting two errors,

```
program fhello_world_mpi.F90
   1
Error: Invalid form of PROGRAM statement at (1)
fhello_world_mpi.F90:2:6:

   use mpi
       1
 Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘mpi.mod’ for reading at (1): 
 No such file or directory
 compilation terminated.
```

I have checked the mpi installation libraries (mpich, openmpi libraries exist in the system).

The program is as follows:

```
program fhello_world_mpi.F90
  use mpi
  implicit none
   integer ( kind = 4 ) error
   integer ( kind = 4 ) id
   integer p
   character(len=MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME) :: name
   integer clen
   integer, allocatable :: mype(:)
   real ( kind = 8 ) wtime

   call MPI_Init ( error )
   call MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, p, error )
   call MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, id, error )
  if ( id == 0 ) then
     wtime = MPI_Wtime ( )

     write ( *, '(a)' ) ' '
     write ( *, '(a)' ) 'HELLO_MPI - Master process:'
     write ( *, '(a)' ) '  FORTRAN90/MPI version'
     write ( *, '(a)' ) ' '
     write ( *, '(a)' ) '  An MPI test program.'
     write ( *, '(a)' ) ' '
     write ( *, '(a,i8)' ) '  The number of processes is ', p
     write ( *, '(a)' ) ' '
  end if
  call MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME(NAME, CLEN, ERROR)
  write ( *, '(a)' ) ' '
  write ( *, '(a,i8,a,a)' ) '  Process ', id, ' says "Hello, world!" ',name(1:clen)

  call MPI_Finalize ( error )
end program
```

**Update1**

Removing the period solved the first problem.
I used these commands:

`mpif90 fhello_world_mpi.F90` and

`mpirun -np 2 ./fhello_world_mpi`

It gave the following errors:

```
mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not 
access or execute an executable:

Executable: ./fhello_world_mpi
Node: user

  while attempting to start process rank 0.
```

---

```
 2 total processes failed to start``
```

**Update2**
It worked.
Ran commands:

`mpif90 -o fhello_world_mpi fhello_world_mpi.F90`

`mpirun -np 2 ./fhello_world_mpi`

***Output***

```
HELLO_MPI - Master process:
  FORTRAN90/MPI version

  An MPI test program.

  The number of processes is        2



   Process        1 says "Hello, world!" user
   Process        0 says "Hello, world!" user
```

Comment: Can you edit this to show us the command you are using to compile the code, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Change the first line of the program to remove the period.

   ```
   program fhello_world_mpi
   ```

   Periods (`.`) are not allowed in the names of Fortran entities (such as programs, variables, constants, types, *etc*).
2. Try mpif90 filename.F90. The [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) feature is usually implemented as a "library" and for the code to compile, you need to provide extra information: location of the `.mod` files when compiling and of the `lib*.so` files when linking. This is achieved by the compiler wrapper mpif90 (often, the name may vary):

   ```
   mpif90 -o fhello_world_mpi fhello_world_mpi.F90
   ```

   Likewise, to execute the code you need a wrapper:

   ```
   mpirun -np 2 ./fhello_world_mpi
   ```

   I assumed the filename was fhello_world_mpi.F90, correct as needed.

In general, you should not try to use the flags manually but if you wish to see them you can use `mpif90 -show`. `mpirun` is needed anyway because it initializes the parallel environment.

Comment: The first point is needed. For "2" I wait for an update from the poster but you are right, as it stands it is not an answer. I usually start by commenting to obtain sufficient information from the poster before replying. I'll wait for feedback here.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Sorry for the delay. The first error has gone with the removal of the period. The second problem persists. I am running "gfortran filename.F90". Is there any other steps to follow to make the mpi working?

Comment: Try `mpif90 filename.F90`. The [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) feature is usually implemented as a "library" and for the code to compile, you need to provide extra information: location of the `.mod` files when compiling and of the `lib*.so` files when linking. This is achieved by the compiler wrapper `mpif90` (often, the name may vary). Likewise, to execute the code you need a wrapper: `mpirun -np 2 ./fhello_world_mpi`.

Comment: You should really use the `mpifort` or `mpif90` wrappers. Unless you specify an executable name via the `-o` option, the generated binary will be `a.out`, so you have to `mpirun -np 2 ./a.out`

Comment: First step: compile with `mpif90 -o fhello_world_mpi fhello_world_mpi.F90`. Only then can you run `mpirun -np 2 ./fhello_world_mpi`. I assumed the filename was `fhello_world_mpi.F90`, correct as needed.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Got it working by your last comment. Thank You.